# Accessing file in Vendor folder cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp

In `cakephp` how can I access a file, inside vendor folder?

I am not using app folder. I have created another project folder with same structure of app.

Should I use the same

```
App::import('Vendor','phpseclib0.3.6/Net/SSH2.php');
```

statement or anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vendors libs should follow some name conventions. For libs with custom names us the following:

```
App::import(
    'Vendor',
    'aUniqueIdentifier',
    array('file' => 'phpseclib0.3.6/Net/SSH2.php')
);
```

And read section [Loading Vendor Files](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/app.html#loading-vendor-files)